# How to dynamically change the IP address on a NodeJS web scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, proxy, ip

I'm working on a project for scraping some data (odds) from different sites (bookmakers).
Due to their tracking sistem, sometime i need to change the ip (to be able again to scrape their site).

I know there are services that can help me to solve this problem, like some APIs with the capability of handling the requests for me (hiding me from the sites).
But the problem of those services is that the majority do not have italians IPs, and due to the italian regulation on online gambling, we can bet only on italian bookmakers, and we can access to them only with italian IPs).

But i know that there are services able to provide me tons of italian IPs, and my idea was to solve the problem by:

1. Creating my proxy server to call for handling my request (a server that change IPs when i need).
2. Implement a function able to change the ip of my request made by my scraping tool (the server with the scraping functions).

Honestly i don't know if those ideas could be a valid solution to solve my problem, soo my question is:
How can i implement those features to my code?
And if those options are not valid, is there a solution or a service that i can use? (even if is required a payment or a subscription).

Thanks in advance to all those who will be able to give me a hand!

P.S: I'm still improving my english. I hope I was as correct as possible :)
P.S.2: I'm using NodeJS with the Selenium JavaScript library.